# Classes structure

Tags: php, oop

I am quite confused about this subject, let's say I have a Authentication class (logging in, logging out, checking if logged in or not)

A User class (that holds a User, getters, setters, save etc)

Where should I put stuff like creating a User, and like validating a Username? A new class, like "UserManager" or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of a design question, which makes it a little difficult to answer since there probably isn't an objectively right way to do this. Rather, several people have created several different solutions that all work equally well.

One suggestion would be to create a `Users` (plural) class that has public methods like `addNew` (returns `User` object) and `userExists` (returns `Bool`), as well as `validateUsername` (also returning `Bool`).

This `Users` class could contain additional logic used to managing your user-base as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is to include the create/validate/etc.. methods in the user class

```
class user{
       function __construct($iduser){ 
            $this->id=$iduser;


       }

       function getHref(){
         return "/profile/".$this->id;
       }


       function create($username){
           //insert your user in db
           //retrieve the id of the created user
           $iduser=mysql_insert_id();

           $newuser=new user($iduser);
           return $newuser;
       }

       function validate($username){

          mysql_query("your code to validate");

          return true or false;
       }
}

$name="john";
if(user::validate("$name")){
    $mynewuser=user::create("john");

    $href=$mynewuser->getHref();
    header("Location: $href"); //let s redirect him to its home page
    //or use any other method...
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess my solution is very much alike "Jonathan Sampson" one. except I was more verbose